# How to run one airflow task and all its dependencies?

Tags: python-3.6, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I suspected that

`airflow run dag_id task_id execution_date`

would run all upstream tasks, but it does not. It will simply fail when it sees that not all dependent tasks are run. How can I run a specific task and all its dependencies? I am guessing this is not possible because of an airflow design decision, but is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem but don't have a solution. I think there might be a way to get around this using UI and running a task from a dag that is n running state.

Answer (score 9):

You can run a task independently by using -i/-I/-A flags along with the run command.

But yes the design of airflow does not permit running a specific task and all its dependencies.

You can backfill the dag by removing non-related tasks from the DAG for testing purpose

Comment: Then what is the best alternative to airflow to achieve the goal (run a task and its dependencies from a DAG)?

Comment: Azkaban has this feature. in the execute flow popup you can disable any job or disable its upstream dependencies or downstream dependencies and then execute the flow.

https://azkaban.readthedocs.io/en/latest/useAzkaban.html#executing-flow-view

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a workaround but in case you have given your tasks `task_id`-s consistently you can try the backfilling from Airflow CLI (Command Line Interface):

```
airflow backfill -t TASK_REGEX ... dag_id
```

where `TASK_REGEX` corresponds to the naming pattern of the task you want to rerun and its dependencies.

(remember to add the rest of [the command line options](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#backfill), like `--start_date`).