# Re-running Failed SubDAGs

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've been playing around with SubDAGs. A big problem I've faced is whenever something within the SubDAG fails, and I re-run things by hitting Clear, only the cleared task will re-run; the success does not propagate to downstream tasks in the SubDAG and get them running.

How do I re-run a failed task in a SubDAG such that the downstream tasks will flow correctly? Right now, I have to literally re-run every task in the SubDAG that is downstream of the failed task.

I think I followed the best practices of SubDAGs; the SubDAG inherits the Parent DAG properties wherever possible (including `schedule_interval`), and I don't turn the SubDAG on in the UI; the parent DAG is on and triggers it instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run one airflow task and all its dependencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42633892/how-to-run-one-airflow-task-and-all-its-dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a workaround but in case you have given your tasks `task_id`-s consistently you can try the backfilling from Airflow CLI (Command Line Interface):

```
airflow backfill -t TASK_REGEX ... dag_id
```

where `TASK_REGEX` corresponds to the naming pattern of the task you want to rerun and its dependencies.

(remember to add the rest of [the command line options](https://airflow.apache.org/cli.html#backfill), like `--start_date`).